# Executing multiple requests xrm sdk

Tags: c#, ssis, dynamics-crm, crm

I have created a SSIS package to import data from excel file to CRM and currently using ExecuteMultipleRequest to send data to crm in batches. The scenario here is, When I do a create request for 800 records in a batch is there a way to get back 800 guids that got created? If yes, Will I get back the guids in same order?

```
var multipleRequest = new ExecuteMultipleRequest()
            {
                Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings()
                {
                    ContinueOnError = true, // Continue, if processing of a single request fails
                    ReturnResponses = true // Return responses so you can get processing results
                },
                Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
            };

            // Build a CreateRequest for each record
            foreach (var samples in _samples)
            {
                CreateRequest reqCreate = new CreateRequest();
                reqCreate.Target = geocode;
                multipleRequest.Requests.Add(reqCreate);
            }

            ExecuteMultipleResponse multipleResponses = (ExecuteMultipleResponse)Service.Execute(multipleRequest);
```

I'm using this code to process multiple requests as of now.

Thank you

Comment: Yes my question is a duplicate of the one which you shared. Sorry for that and Thank you for sharing the link!